# Non-Authoritative-Reason header field [HTTP]

Tags: google-chrome, http, hsts

I'm having difficulty finding out what it means when I have the response header `Non-Authoritative-Reason : HSTS`

I have searched a lot but just came up with some explanations about HSTS (redirection from HTTP to HTTPS). Can anyone help me with that? By the way I'm using Chrome.

Thanks

Answer (score 85):

The server you are trying to connect with uses strict-transport-security (HSTS) to ensure https only is used with this site rather than the default http.

This means if you enter http://www.servername.com then Chrome will automatically convert this to https://www.servername.com.

This is a security feature to prevent use of http, which is unencrypted and which can be read and altered by a hacker. This can be set by the server telling Chrome (via a special HTTP Header sent in response to requests) that it uses HSTS. This setting is then cached by Chrome for the given amount of time as defined in the max-age value in that header. Additionally the site owner can submit their site to a preload list that is automatically included in Chrome - which protects even the first visit as normally you need to visit the site to receive the header to activate this.

The way Chrome shows this in the network tab is by creating a dummy 307 response with a redirect to the https version of the address. But that's a fake response and is not generated by the server - the reality is Chrome did that internally before the request even went to the server.

To clear this setting for a site you can type the following into Chrome's URL field: `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` and then search for your site and delete it. You may also set this at a top level domain and include subdomains so you may need to delete from there. Alternatively you can just alter your server config to publish the header with a max-age of 0 and revisit the site to clear this, then stop publishing the header, which can be helpful for other browsers where it's not quite as easy to clear this.

Note you cannot clear this setting if a site is on the preload list as this is embedded in the web browser's code. The site owner can submit a request to be removed from the preload list but this takes several months to go through the release cycle for Chrome and no defined timeline for other browsers. Chrome also provides no way to override preloaded settings - for security reasons.

Comment: Is there any way to clear the Chrome cache of which sites trigger this? I am debugging my Apache reverse proxy configuration.

Comment: Added details to my answer.

Comment: That's the Chrome preload list. There are other lists for other browsers.

Comment: Well, I am facing the similar issue. I tried to clear the site hrome://net-internals/#hsts I couldn't find one there. But still I get  response header Non-Authoritative-Reason : HSTS. Same website URL works in Firefox when I try the same thing in chrome I get HSTS. Does anyone have any other solution to fix this issue?

Comment: Check the header is not being set on the top level domain. E.g. it might be set on example.com with includeSubDomain option but you only checked www.example.com.

Answer (score 11):

Some additional info to BazzaDP's answer...

The `Non-Authoritative-Reason : HSTS` returned in the response is not something you have configured, but rather Chrome itself. Since Chrome hijacks the request, Chrome will also add this particular header to tell HSTS is enabled. Looking at the network tab, you will see the fake 307 response with this header set.

All this is done since *you* included the `Strict-Transport-Security` header on your server.

If you want to go all in, here's the [HSTS preload list](https://hstspreload.org/)

Answer (score 1):

According to MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security):

> The `Strict-Transport-Security` header is ignored by the browser when
>   your site is accessed using **HTTP**; this is because an attacker may
>   intercept HTTP connections and inject the header or remove it

And the HSTS Preload list [deployment recommendations](https://hstspreload.org/#deployment-recommendations) mention:

> Add the `Strict-Transport-Security` header to all **HTTPS** responses

The [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/master/dist/.htaccess) shows how to only set `Strict-Transport-Security` over HTTPS (in apache):

```
# Set 'Strict-Transport-Security' over HTTPS only!
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:PROTO}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```