# Should UseHsts apply headers to static files added via UseStaticFiles

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-5, hsts

We are running a .net 5 web app.

We use both `UseStaticFiles` and `UseHsts` in our app `Configure()` at startup.

I can access my static files.

All my API/dynamic web endpoints have the HSTS headers.

My static files do not have the HSTS headers.

We have some static HTML files used in a SPA app and the pen tests we run are triggering vulnerabilities on it when it scans.

How can i configure my static files to use HSTS headers.

```
// Simplified example
public void Configure(
    IApplicationBuilder app,
    IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime
)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseHsts();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCors();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/healthcheck");
    });
}
```

---

Update based on @gjhommersom awnser

Configuring the app like this instead adds cors to the headers.

However the strict-transport-security header is still missing :(

```
// Simplified example
public void Configure(
    IApplicationBuilder app,
    IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime
)
{
    app.UseHsts();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCors();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/healthcheck");
    });
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

Comment: Add `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` behind the `app.UseHsts();`? I found that [this high-vote answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55301687) said use hsts made http request automatically switch to https. So I think you need to add that code-line.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware the order of setting up your application is important. Have you tried calling `UseHsts()` before `UseStaticFiles()`?

Reason being that the static file middleware returns a file before the hsts middleware can do the redirect.

Similar issue: [Why does order between UseStaticFiles and UseDefaultFiles matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53988848/why-does-order-between-usestaticfiles-and-usedefaultfiles-matter)

Comment: A solid idea however changing this does not fix the issue, I update my question to include your idea.