# Kenticp Requires SSL redirecting with 307 instead of 301

Tags: redirect, https, kentico, kentico-12

Under Kentico settings I have `Allow permanent (301) redirection: true` and all pages set to Require SSL.

When I call a page with http it redirects with a 307 and then a 301 response instead of a straight 301 response. Is there any way to force just the 301 response?

I'm using K12 Portal Engine

Edit: Solved the issue. It's a response header causing chrome to insert the 307. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34108241/non-authoritative-reason-header-field-http/)

Comment: What hotfix is installed? What is the IIS setup? Are you using any URL rewriting rules? I just tried it on my Kentico 12 PE site with latest hotfix and I am getting correct 301 status code for the HTTP -> HTTPS redirection. Nothing in-between. https://www.screencast.com/t/tMrai7HmQs and https://www.screencast.com/t/jzY3ylNGjhKy

Comment: Problem solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34108241/non-authoritative-reason-header-field-http/