# DNS resolves correctly using command line tools but fails on browser

Tags: amazon-s3, browser, dns, amazon-route53, request-timed-out

`Dig`, `wget`, `nslookup` and `curl` commands work perfectly for a specific URL I have pointed to another server less than 24 hours ago.
Problem is, it just refuses to be resolved by the browser (Chrome, Safari and Firefox). The strangest part is that it is being successfully resolved by Postman (by testing the OPTIONS and the GET methods separately), but still doesn't return a proper response on the browser side of things.
DNS checks are returning positive, so this is when I started suspecting that the problem is actually within the headers of the HTTP protocol's requests which are sent - alongside the fact that different responses are being returned for the requests that don't include the default browser headers (being issued through the different command-line tools & Postman) and the ones who do (being issued by the browsers automatically or manually using the dev tools).
After fully flushing the current local system's DNS cache, including the browsers's and even trying another device on another network - I still get still no response on the browser.
Kept going, and attempted to verify that with a VPN (locally - which didn't work), and an online web proxy tool (which did work).
Finally, I extracted the router's default DNS server address, used `nslookup` to look up the URL again, this time specifically mentioning the desired DNS server (the one stated above), and after getting a successful response with the correct values, I am now pretty much sure the HTTP request is causing the problem.

The URL is hosted on Amazon S3 Static Hosting option, which I used many times before, and didn't have a problem with, with that exact same configuration. Looking up the recent changes/features that were possibly added, pointed out that I may need to explicitly set a CORS policy for the newly created bucket, on top of the usual public access policy that is needed.
After applying that as-well - it still doesn't seem to work.

As a quick change in direction that may possibly make some parts clearer about what's going on (and as I started to think that the browser might not be getting the correct `Content-Type` header in the response, which should be `text/html` header as its response, and therefore, possibly doesn't resolve the URL with the expected behavior), I went ahead and applied a 301 redirection on the S3 bucket, instead of the static files hosting, and again, it all works perfectly through the command line tools, but not through the browsers.
Anyway, the browser just doesn't seem to complete any of the requests being sent to the URL.
That might be the `OPTIONS` pre-flight request failing to respond correctly, and the browser just doesn't continue to issuing the `GET` request, or the URL is not being found by the DNS route the browser is taking, which is unclear to me currently if that is the option.

Any ideas? (besides the fact that sometimes it just takes longer time for some DNS servers that happen to be on the chosen route to update/refresh their cache, which doesn't appear to be affecting my local machine's DNS route specifically for this case. That, being said with caution, was verified by validating the different parts of DNS configuration and prioritization throughout the different possible parts on my system (Mac OS X), including the fact that the response gets back with the correct address successfully).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/942030/aws-s3-static-hosting-how-to-debug-connection-timeout

As linked there, more details can be found here:
[Non-Authoritative-Reason header field [HTTP]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34108241/non-authoritative-reason-header-field-http)

Solution & Explanation: Because of the nature of the domain extension I have purchased (.dev extension) Chrome was silently using `HTTPS` because of the URL being part of `Chrome's HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)`, because all .dev domains should be using HTTPS only. Therefore, the issue was still showing up, even when explicitly typing `http://` into the URL address bar.

This can be overridden by applying a CloudFront distribution with HTTPS support on top of the S3 Static Hosting, as usual (but still, it should be noted as HSTS listings can cause that for different cases, including this one as part of them, because of the .dev domain extension).

[image]

[image]

**Useful Resources (for debugging purposes)**

1. In addition to what is stated here:
   https://gist.github.com/stollcri/7c09bafc97223481920e
   You can issue a lookup query (and also add or delete your local set of HSTS listings) through the following Chrome's settings URL:
   [image]
2. You can also check the current listings here: https://hstspreload.org/