# 307 Internal Redirect Non-Authoritative-Reason: DNS

Tags: google-chrome, https

I search everywhere I found 0 information about this specific redirect.

I have app that I need to use "HTTP" to function, recently chrome started to redirect my app to HTTPS  automatically, and If I put HTTPS to HTTP code in my app it cause infinite loop.

My app is not on the HSTS preload domain list, my app and server have no redirect code to HTTPS.

Request URL: http://4444.com/z.txt
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 307 Internal Redirect (from disk cache)
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: Cross-Origin
Location: https://4444.com/z.txt
Non-Authoritative-Reason: DNS

This does not happen on any other browser other than chrome.

Does that mean chrome is targeting my host's dns to make sure all website hosted on the DNS is HTTPS?

If yes I think this is very bad move from google as I can't find any announcement by google that they will start forcing https on websites. This could break many non https sites without prior warning.

If not what can I do to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem just like you, and that situation didn't happen  all the time, sometimes when I open another window as incognito mode, the redirect disappeared!Sooooo Annoying:(

And I just tried another way, it seemed to work fine with me!

go to : `chrome://net-internals/#dns`, and click *Clear host cache* , then refresh your page, the redirect will be gone!

Comment: I did that for another site that only works in HTTP and the redirect DID NOT disappear. Moreover it writes "from disk cache" even though cache is cleared and disabled. Irritating. Will switch to Edge for this.

Comment: Try `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` instead, your site might be cached by Chrome's list of HSTS domains, you can search/query for your domain and delete it from the cached list. (credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34213531/61697)

Answer (score 1):

Did you access websites using VPN? VPN server seems able to force http to https

Answer (score 1):

Even if the "Always use secure connections"  (`chrome://settings/security`) is disabled, chrome will still try to use HTTPS if it finds HTTPS records in DNS, as per `#dns-https-svcb` flag - "Support for HTTPS records in DNS" (`chrome://flags/#dns-https-svcb`) - which is enabled by default.

This causes the loop leading to the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS with Non-Authoritative-Reason: DNS.

Either remove any HTTPS record from the host zone file or disable the aforementioned flag from chrome.

Comment: Thank you for this, it was driving me crazy. Can you please clarify what you mean by "remove any HTTPS record from the host zone file"? Are those records stored locally somewhere?

Comment: @AlexandrinRus [Zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file) are served by authoritative [name servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_server), locally you only have a lookups cache.
While you can run a nameserver yourself (or any dns based ad blocking software) to override the response, for an end-user I'd recommend to simply disable the flag.

Comment: Ok, I was kind of hoping it's a behaviour that occurs on a device-level basis and would be preventable in another way. As the authoritative name servers are not under our control, I guess there's no easy way to clear HTTPS records on those. My concern is that Chrome will force new users that have never even visited our domain before to the secured endpoint based on DNS lookups. We have some urls that we are required to serve on `http://` and will not work correctly if forced on `https://`. If I were to enforce http by code it will end up in a redirect loop. Thank you for the clarifications.

Comment: @AlexandrinRus Just to clarify a bit further, if the flag is left enabled, this is the behavior that any Chrome user will experience regardless if they have a cached lookup. 
As soon as the cache expires (as per TTL), chrome will perform a new lookup and if the HTTPS record is still there, it will try to redirect the client.

Comment: Got it, thank you. I guess the only solution would be not to support https at all on those domains and not get to have any records cached, which isn't ideal. I at least think Chrome should have a bit more transparency on these type of changes and at least allow some kind of exclusion configuration to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on three devices on Chrome, one of them got fixed by turning the VPN off, and in other cases was redirecting even when "Always use secure connections" was off, turning off the "Use secure DNS" in the chrome://settings/security fixed it.